# "commence before first target. Stop." error

Tags: makefile

In *.mak file I receive commands "commence before first target. Stop."
I didn't change it before.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: How about posting the file contents?

Comment: What's a *.mak-file? Not even http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?al=M mentions it. 
What are you trying to do?
What exactly is this about?
If this is about make, then which incarnation of it are you using? There are plenty of makes.

Comment: The question does not appear to have anything to do with c or c++, so I edited the tags. I *could* do with and indication of just what build system you are using, however. Try `make --version` or check with the make manpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [{Makefile Error} "commands commence before first target. Stop."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238223/makefile-error-commands-commence-before-first-target-stop)

Answer (score 72):

`make` (or `NMAKE`, or whatever flavour of make you are using) can be quite picky about the format of makefiles - check that you didn't actually edit the file in any way, e.g. changed line endings, spaces <-> tabs, etc.

Comment: I got a build error due to a tab space after my line..this helped

Comment: a line before the error line, I had a tab space also

Comment: In my case I had an equal sign (=) in the file name of the source code. Once I replaced it by a dash (-) the makefile worked just fine.

Answer (score 54):

This means that there is a line which starts with a space, tab, or some other whitespace without having a target in front of it.

Answer (score 20):

if you have added a new line, Make sure you have added next line syntax in previous line. typically if "\" is missing in your previous line of changes, you will get this error.

Comment: In particular, you can't even have a line ending with whitespace after the backslash!

Answer (score 9):

This could be echoing outside the target, for instance

```
# Variable 
BAR = 
ifeq ($(FOO), 1)
    @echo "FooBar"  <----- generate the error
    BAR += foobar
endif
 
# Targets
all: 
...
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, make sure you dont have a space after \ in previous line 
Else this is the error

Comment: This is the sneaky one that got me, since the error message points to the line that isn't actually the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple Mistake while adding a new file you just have to make sure that `\` is added to the file before and the new file  remain as it is
eg.

[Check Out what to do if i want to add a new file named customer.cc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beXYL.png)

Answer (score 0):

This could also caused by mismatching brace/parenthesis.

```
$(TARGET}:
    do_something
```

Just use parenthesises and you'll be fine.