# echoing string in Linux Kernel Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I've time and again used the standard `Makefile` for building out of tree modules. It is reproduced below:

```
# Comment/uncomment the following line to disable/enable debugging
DEBUG = y

# Add your debugging flag (or not) to CFLAGS
ifeq ($(DEBUG),y)
    DEBFLAGS = -O0 -g3 -DSCULL_DEBUG # "-O" is needed to expand inlines
else
    DEBFLAGS = -O2
endif

LDDINC=$(PWD)/../include

EXTRA_CFLAGS += $(DEBFLAGS)
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -I$(LDDINC)


ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    # call from kernel build system
    @echo 'called from kernel build system' #<-- FAILS HERE
    scull-objs := main.o pipe.o access.o
    obj-m   := scull.o
else
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD       := $(shell pwd)
    modules:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif

install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install
    cd /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r) && depmod -a

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions

depend .depend dep:
    $(CC) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) -M *.c > .depend


ifeq (.depend,$(wildcard .depend))
include .depend
endif
```

I would like `make` to print custom string messages as it processes this Makefile so I tried adding `@echo` messages (see *`FAILS HERE`* in the code). But doing so fails with the following error:

> Makefile:25: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.

the offending line is marked above. Is there anyway I can do what I intend to do?

Comment: Remove the leading tabs in lines that are not recipes. Tabs are meaningful for make, you should not use them just to indent the content of `ifneq...else...endif`.

Comment: Use simple `$(info MESSAGE)`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yes you were right. With echo it doesn't work when TABs are added to something that is not a recipe. Thank you. Do you blog somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["commence before first target. Stop." error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912689/commence-before-first-target-stop-error)